# How do I split this string up?

Tags: python, io

```
...    
    1947q2        -0.6
    1947q3        -0.3
    1947q4         6.2
    1948q1        16.5
...
```

How do I get this text file into a list? I'm having problems with the spacing between the year and corresponding values.

This is what I have so far:

```
data = []

for line in open("file"):
    if '1947' in line:
        sl = line.split('       ')
        data.append((sl[0], sl[1]))

print data
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just using `split()` without arguments splits by whitespace, and eats consecutive whitespace:

```
>>> s='    1947q2        -0.6'
>>> s.split()
['1947q2', '-0.6']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = []

with open("file") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        data.append(tuple(line.split()))

print data
```

Comment: Or while we're at it: `data = [tuple(line.split()) for line in open("file") if '1947' in line]` :P

Comment: @Thomas, or even `map(str.split, open("file"))` :P

Comment: Well yeah. :P Just tried to be closer to the question and use "with".

Answer (score 0):

One liner using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and a couple shortcuts in reading the data:

```
data = [line.split() for line in open('path/to/file', 'rt')]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `.readlines()` here. You can just iterate over the file object and it means it doesn't all get read into memory at once

Comment: @gnibbler:  Thanks.  I removed it.